# MySQL: How to query to get record in a specific position?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a simple table (product) with fields id, label.

I want to get the n-th unique row from it. If i query like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id ASC WHERE id ='.$n;
```

where $n is a number it will return the row that id = number but my table is something like this:

```
id | label
 1 | sometext
 4 | sometext
33 | sometext
40 | sometext
```

..

i mean, if i want to get the 3-th row which is ( 33 | sometext ) the query wont work.
Is there a simple way to get the 3-th or 4-th row ?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? can't you add an "order" column and then fetch using that? Do you always want the third row no matter what it contains?

Comment: You achieve that by using `OFFSET, LIMIT` in MySQL, you don't rely on the primary key for such purposes. If you have 10 records and you want  3rd (it's not 3-th), you use: `SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2, 1`. That will start at record number 2 and limit the results to 1, effectively giving you the 3rd record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2,1"
```

will get you the third row

Comment: TY Damien , works as i wanted and also can see i am not a coder ; )

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id LIMIT 2,1;`

This will get the 3rd row from the table.

`2` is the start point

`1` is the number of results returned

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT * 
   FROM product 
   ORDER BY id ASC 
   LIMIT'.$n.' )
ORDER BY ID DSC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thanks Zohaib but think is more complicated to understand as the previews answer. Do you think is there any advantage in using this query?